# How to change image set on Button

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to change the button image on buttons click event. Here is what i am trying.

```
-(IBAction)editObjectImage:(id)sender
{
    if (editButtonState == NO)
    {   
        [editButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [editButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"done2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [editButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [editButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

But my Button image is not changing. What's wrong with code?

Comment: Make sure the file name passed to imageNamed function is correct!

Answer (score 10):

I think you aren't getting round to changing `editButtonState`. Your code can be reduced to.

```
-(IBAction)editObjectImage:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *theButton = (UIButton*)sender;
    if (editButtonState == NO) {   
        [theButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"done2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [theButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    editButtonState = !editButtonState;
}
```

Comment: Have you connected the outlet?

Comment: YES. Because it Perform another work but button image is not change.

Comment: Another work? Do you mean action? or updating the button's other properties?

Comment: two action will perform on edit button click event.
1.) Edit button image change.
2.) a function call(It work properly).

Comment: It's probable that you've connected only the action and not the outlet. Both are different things. I've edited my code. See if it works now.

Comment: Do the images exist? Is it a `UIButton` instance?

Comment: Can you log the button like `NSLog(@"%@", editButton);` and post it here?

Comment: Also, make sure the file name passed to imageNamed function is correct!

Answer (score 4):

This is my working code:

```
NSString *shoppingListButtonImageName = @"notepad-selected";

UIImage *slImage = [UIImage imageNamed:shoppingListButtonImageName];
//put a breakpoint here to check that slImage is not nil.

[self.shoppingListButton setImage:slImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 2):

On button click you have to set image like this;

```
[editButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: i have also tried it. but it not work then i use UIControlstateNormal

Answer (score 0):

Check if the images are added properly (your [UIImage imageNamed:@""]) is not returning nil ? , otherwise it should work properly.